# The method setImageUrl(String, ImageLoader) in the type NetworkImageView is not applicable for the arguments (Uri, ImageLoader)

Tags: java, android, json, android-layout, android-activity

In brief, I am trying to populate an activity that would display information populated from JSON data. I have successfully managed to retrieve strings, but the issue resolves around retrieving images and casting it to imageviews.

I have received the following error in eclipse:

```
The method setImageUrl(String, ImageLoader) in the type NetworkImageView is not applicable for the arguments (Uri, ImageLoader)" at the line hsvimage1.setImageUrl(url1, mImageLoader)
```

for the following lines:

```
        hsvimage1.setImageUrl(url1, mImageLoader);
        hsvimage2.setImageUrl(url2, mImageLoader);
        hsvimage3.setImageUrl(url3, mImageLoader);
```

Below is the entire activity code

```
public class CasualEventsSingleItemActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare Variables
    String list_item_name;
    String list_item_description;
    Uri list_item_bac;

    String list_item_price;
    String list_item_location;

    String single_list_item_description;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_single_item);


        ImageLoader mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(Volley.newRequestQueue(this),
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                    cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return cache.get(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                cache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        });


        Intent i = getIntent();
        list_item_name = i.getStringExtra("list_item_name");
        list_item_location = i.getStringExtra("list_item_location");
        list_item_bac = Uri.parse(i.getStringExtra("list_item_bac"));




        single_list_item_description = i.getStringExtra("single_list_item_description");

        TextView txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView txtlocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
        TextView txtsdescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sdescription);


        NetworkImageView hsvimage1 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage1);
        NetworkImageView hsvimage2 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage2);
        NetworkImageView hsvimage3 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage3);

        // Get image URLs from your previous network request...
        // I could not determine where this is stored from code in your question.
        Uri url1 = list_item_bac;   // e.g. http://example.com/images/image1.png
        Uri url2 = list_item_bac;
        Uri url3 = list_item_bac;

        // Set the URL of the image that should be loaded into this view, and
        // specify the ImageLoader that will be used to make the request.
        hsvimage1.setImageUrl(url1, mImageLoader);
        hsvimage2.setImageUrl(url2, mImageLoader);
        hsvimage3.setImageUrl(url3, mImageLoader);

        // Set results to the TextViews
        txtname.setText(list_item_name);
        txtlocation.setText(list_item_location);
        txtsdescription.setText(single_list_item_description);


        Button mConfirm2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bConfirm2);
        mConfirm2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

               // Create the class and the columns
                currentUser.saveInBackground();

                currentUser.put("ActivityName", list_item_name); 
                currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                        if (e == null) {
                            // Success!
                            Intent intent = new Intent(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this, usermatch.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                   }
               });
                //CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this, MatchingActivity.class));
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Layout for this activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_bac3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:alpha="0.9"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="3"
        android:shadowDy="3"
        android:shadowRadius="0.01"
        android:textColor="#82CAFF"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="3"
        android:shadowDy="3"
        android:shadowRadius="0.01"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dividertop"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/location"
        android:alpha="0.6"
        android:background="@drawable/divider11"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dividerbottom"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vsvdescription"
       android:alpha="0.6"
        android:background="@drawable/divider11"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_head"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/isgallery"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dividerbottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
         >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

               <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/hsvimage1"
                android:layout_width="148dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:padding="1dp" />
               <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/hsvimage2"
                android:layout_width="148dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:padding="1dp" />
               <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/hsvimage3"
                android:layout_width="148dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#CCC"
                android:padding="1dp" />
               <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/hsvimage4"
                android:layout_width="148dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:padding="1dp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                  </HorizontalScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bConfirm2"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/isgallery"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_bac"
        android:text="Confirm"
        android:textColor="#2B3856"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

     <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/vsvdescription"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp" 
        android:padding="5dp"       

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dividertop"
         >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sdescription"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:alpha="0.65"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Update logcat message

```
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 1247
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.volley.Request.<init>(Request.java:130)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest.<init>(ImageRequest.java:71)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.get(ImageLoader.java:220)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.get(ImageLoader.java:171)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView.loadImageIfNecessary(NetworkImageView.java:140)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView.onLayout(NetworkImageView.java:180)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1660)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.onLayout(HorizontalScrollView.java:1474)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make them strings as the method asks for.

```
String url1 = list_item_bac;   // e.g. http://example.com/images/image1.png
        String url2 = list_item_bac;
        String url3 = list_item_bac;
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. What happens when I apply your suggestion is that I can't refer to the Uri when I make them a string and receives an error at the following line list_item_bac = Uri.parse(i.getStringExtra("list_item_bac"));

Comment: its already a tring, why would you parse it into a uri? `getSTRINGExtra`

Comment: thanks for your response. The problem when I change it to the following line: list_item_bac = i.getStringExtra("list_item_bac");
I recieve the following error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Uri

Comment: Initially it was like that - all strings but I ran into the nullpoint exception error (added the logcat message under my initial post under the update section) so tried to adjust the code in order to resolve the issue

Comment: any guidance would be greatly appreciated as i have been struggling with this issue since a while

Answer (score 1):

Edited.

See here for same issue [Convert Uri to String and String to Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324482/convert-uri-to-string-and-string-to-uri)

Comment: why convert string to uri, then back?

Comment: The problem when I change it to the following line: list_item_bac = i.getStringExtra("list_item_bac"); I recieve the following error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Uri