# How to remember bitmap Uri

Tags: java, android, bitmap, sharedpreferences

i'm trying to do an activity which can show picture from gallery. But my `Activity` needs to remember bitmap uri for another time so it can always open that picture.
here is my .java

### **edited**

i added something else to convert uri to `string` then `string` to `uri` but it doesn't work. Can someone help?

```
public class DersProgram extends Activity {  private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dersprogrami);

    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
         Uri uri = data.getData();         
        String BitmapURI;
        BitmapURI = uri.toString();
        uri = Uri.parse(BitmapURI);


        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("BitmapURI", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("BitmapURI", "your URI as a String").apply();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.resim);

        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            bmp = getBitmapFromUri(uri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    }


}



private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
            getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
    parcelFileDescriptor.close();
    return image;
}
```

}

I want to open picture which is called before. Please help me(also i am a beginner) sorry for my English.

Comment: Google for `shared preferences`.

Answer (score 0):

As said, use SharedPreferences.

store your bitmapURI as a String in your Activity:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("some string", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("BitmapURI", "your URI as a String").apply();
```

and retrieve it whenever your want:

```
String bitmapURI = sharedPreferences.getString("BitmapURI", "default string if BitmapURI is not set");
```

Comment: By the way, for Uri to String transformation look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324482/convert-uri-to-string-and-string-to-uri.