# Convert String to Uri in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, uri

How can I convert a String to a Uri in Kotlin instead of java (Android)?

```
val Uri_string = "/sdcard/example.jpg"
```

**Uri_string = ???;**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324482/convert-uri-to-string-and-string-to-uri?rq=1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
val uri = Uri.parse(Uri_string)
```

or

```
val fileName = "example.jpg"
val path = "${Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()}/$fileName"
val file = File(path); 
val uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [Android KTX](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx) you can also parse this way:

```
val uri_string = "/sdcard/example.jpg"
val uri = uri_string.toUri()
```